# Isotope itemSelector on visible items

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

This is my js code:

```
var $container = $('.lista').isotope({
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    itemSelector: '.prodotti'
});
```

I would filter the items ".prodotti" taking only the visible ones. I tried to use:

```
itemSelector: '.prodotti:visible'
```

but nothing happens. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
var onlyVisible = $('.prodotti').filter(':visible');
var $container = $('.lista').isotope({
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  itemSelector: onlyVisible
});
```

or you can make use of `filter`:

```
var $container = $('.lista').isotope({
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  itemSelector: '.prodotti',
  filter: ':visible'
});
```